# Check the paging space utilization of the server in unix?

Tags: java, shell, unix, aix

I need to check whether a java process is consuming more paging space in linux and AIX.

Comment: Paging is something the computer does not a resource which is used. It's like looking for "network space". Are you asking about memory utilisation or disk bandwidth utilisation?/

Comment: yep memory utilisation or disk bandwidth utilisation..

Comment: These are very different things. For memory are you looking at virtual memory size, resident memory size, size swapped to disk, shared memory size?

Comment: virtual memory size

Comment: You can get a detail analysis of the virtual memory size of a process on linux by reading `/proc/{pid}/maps` From Java you can read `/proc/self/maps` which is likely to be more than you every wanted to know. Note: the virtual memory size is *virtual* so it can be many TBs and yet consume very little (as opposed to resident memory size which is the actual amount used)

Answer (score 1):

> virtual memory size

To get just the virtual memory size you can read `/proc/self/maps` on Linux which has all the address ranges used. Take the different and you will know how much virtual memory is being used for what.

If you want more detail such as the resident size you can read `/proc/self/smaps`

This gives fine grain detail on every mapping including how much is private, dirty, swapped etc.

```
00400000-004f4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 12058626                           /bin/bash
Size:                976 kB
Rss:                 888 kB
Pss:                 177 kB
Shared_Clean:        888 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:          888 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd ex mr mw me dw sd
```

Comment: when i execute this command /proc/self/maps

I got this error  `-bash: /proc/self/maps: Permission denied` @Peter Lawrey

Comment: @SuganthanRaj Indeed, I don't suggest you try running it as a program as it's not an executable. It's a file you **read**

Answer (score 0):

list how much swap each process is using  (linux )
for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done